# Show uploaded files to Anonymous user but only allow download from registered

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

On Drupal 6 I am attaching a file to a node. This can be done using the core upload module or as a CCK field (What ever will achieve the permissions issue).

I would like anonymous users to be able to see the file, but once they click on it to be prompted to login or register. Once logged in (or registered) then to be taken to either the same page they started on or start the download.

Not really sure where to start on this (related to the permissions and then the eventual redirect).

One method that i would do is in the template files detect if there is a userid variable (To indicate they are logged in), if there is show the link to the file - if they are not then to send to the login/registration page.  I can store the link they wanted in the user session.  But then how would i detect their registration is complete and redirect them to the page/file?

Ideally there is a module (which I am still hunting around for) that does this task!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just need to set the destination parameter, this works for the basic login/registration form. If you however require something like email confirmation for registration, then it's going to be a lot more complicated.

Example Links:

user/login?destination=download_url
user/register?destination=download_url

There is also an API function that will automatically generate the destination part for the current URL: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_destination/7.